# node.js mongo connection spike, write fail, connection pooling

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a very simple logging application written in node that stores data in mongo.  It runs fine for a while (an hour), and then the amount of connections spike and all my writes fail for a while before the connections go down (presumably they timeout).  I know calling `db.close()` is important, and the event based, asynchronous aspect of node makes it not trivial on where to make that call.

In my request handler, I have:

```
//val is an object previously defined
database.writeRecord(val)
database.userExists(val['cookie'], function(c){//returns 1 if user exists, 0 if not
  if(c==0)  
    database.createNewUserProfile(val['cookie'],'campaign',val, {cid:cid, event:event});
  else
    database.attachEventToUserProfile(val['cookie'], 'campaign',val, {cid:cid, event:event});
});
```

Then, in my database handler, I have the following functions (forgive the length of this copy/paste):

```
function writeRecord(object_passbyreference){
    //make a deep copy
    var value = new Object();
    for (var attr in object_passbyreference) {
        value[attr] = object_passbyreference[attr];
    }
    if(additionalattributes!=undefined){//is there anything else i want to throw in this record?
        for (var attr in additionalattributes) 
            value[attr] = additionalattributes[attr];
    }


    dbname='beacon';
    collectionname='testcollection';

    var db = new Db(dbname, new Server(host, port, {}), {native_parser:false});
    db.open(function(err, db) {
        if(db === null)
            console.log('                                                         db is undefined');
        else{
            db.collection(collectionname, function(err, collection) {
                collection.insert(value, function(err,doc){
                    if(err) {  
                        console.log('Insert ERROR!!!!! Is the database running? '+JSON.stringify(err));
                    }
                    db.close();
                }) // collection.insert
            }); //db.collection
        }
    }); // db.open
}



function userExists(cookieid, callback){
    var db = new Db('beacon', new Server(host, port, {}), {native_parser:false});
    db.open(function(err, db) {//opendb++
        if(db === null)
            console.log('                                                         db is undefined - profile');
        else{ 
            db.collection('userprofiles', function(err, collection) {
                collection.find({cookie:cookieid}).toArray(function(e, results) {
                    if(e){
                        console.log ('  ERROR IN saveUserProfileEvent error:'+JSON.stringify(e)+"    cookie:"+JSON.stringify({cookie:cookieid}));
                    }
                    else{//the query went alright, callback the count ...
                        callback(results.length)//returns the size of the result set
                    }
                    db.close();
                })
            })
        }
    })
}

function createNewUserProfile(cookieid, eventtype, object_passbyreference, additionalattributes){
    //make a deep copy, clone it
    var object = new Object();
    for (var attr in object_passbyreference) {
        if(attr!='cookie')
            object[attr] = object_passbyreference[attr];
    }
    if(additionalattributes!=undefined){//is there anything else i want to throw in this record?
        for (var attr in additionalattributes) 
            object[attr] = additionalattributes[attr];
    }
    var recordtosave=new Object();
    recordtosave['cookie']=cookieid;

    recordtosave['items']=1;//keep this here, maybe just for fun, let's see if we can keep a count of total entries for this given user
    recordtosave['campaign']=new Array();//new Array();
    recordtosave['survey']=new Array();
    recordtosave[eventtype]=[object];

    recordtosave['demographics']=new Object();
    recordtosave['demographics']['age']=functionobj.getAge();
    recordtosave['demographics']['gender']=functionobj.getGender();
    recordtosave['demographics']['income']=functionobj.getIncome();

    var db = new Db('beacon', new Server(host, port, {}), {native_parser:false});
    db.open(function(err, db) {//opendb++
        if(db === null)
            console.log('                                                         db is undefined - profile');
        else{ 
            db.collection('userprofiles', function(err, collection) {
                collection.insert(recordtosave, function(err,doc){
                    if(err){
                        console.log('        ERROR Adding new user '+cookieid);
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log('Added new user '+cookieid);
                    }
                    db.close();
                })
            })
        }
    })
}


function attachEventToUserProfile(cookieid, eventtype, object_passbyreference, additionalattributes){
    var object = new Object();
    for (var attr in object_passbyreference) {
        if(attr!='cookie')
            object[attr] = object_passbyreference[attr];
    }
    if(additionalattributes!=undefined){//is there anything else i want to throw in this record?
        for (var attr in additionalattributes) 
            object[attr] = additionalattributes[attr];
    }


    var db = new Db('beacon', new Server(host, port, {}), {native_parser:false});
    db.open(function(err, db) {
        if(db === null)
            console.log('                                                         db is undefined - profile');
        else{ 
            db.collection('userprofiles', function(err, collection) {
                eventtopush=new Object();
                eventtopush[eventtype]=object
                collection.update({cookie: cookieid}, {$inc: { 'items' : 1 }, $push: eventtopush}, function(e,doc){
                    if(e){
                        console.log('        ERROR Updating user '+cookieid);
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log('Updated user '+cookieid);
                    }
                    db.close();
                });
            })
        }
    });
}
```

All my functions are of the form:

```
function f(param, callback){
  db=new db;
  db.open(...
    db.collection(....
      db.find/insert(....
        callback()
        db.close()
}
```

Is that correct? I want the db.close at the end of the inner most function call, right? That means it will execute after everything has finished?  Is this the correct method to do a mongo query in node?

Viewing mongostat, I see that my connections are very low and flat, and then, in a while, they spike to ~800 and my writes start failing (note, the time interval on this is 15 seconds):

```
    72     55     38      0       0     332  1.02g    62m      0    90k   307k    13  RTR   21:01:26 
    68     52     37      0       0     316  1.03g    62m      0    85k   250k    12  RTR   21:01:41 
    81     65     50      0       0     368  1.02g    62m      0   101k   280k     5  RTR   21:01:56 
    70     54     39      0       0     322  1.02g    62m      0    87k   306k     4  RTR   21:02:11 
insert  query update delete getmore command  vsize    res faults  netIn netOut  conn repl       time 
    73     52     36      0       0     334  1.09g    63m      0    88k   235k    79  RTR   21:02:26 
    73     55     39      0       0     346  1.15g    64m      0    91k   250k   148  RTR   21:02:41 
    70     59     42      0       0     328  1.02g    62m      0    90k   269k    26  RTR   21:02:56 
    73     58     43      0       0     346  1.02g    62m      0    93k   303k     3  RTR   21:03:11 
    71     55     41      0       0     337  1.02g    62m      0    90k   243k    16  RTR   21:03:26 
    69     55     40      0       0     329  1.02g    62m      0    88k   322k     8  RTR   21:03:41 
    70     56     42      0       0     338  1.02g    62m      0    91k   261k     5  RTR   21:03:56 
    67     52     38      0       0     316  1.02g    62m      0    85k   261k     3  RTR   21:04:11 
    64     50     36      0       0     306  1.02g    62m      0    82k   243k    25  RTR   21:04:26 
    61     48     37      0       0     294  1.04g    62m      0    78k   259k    32  RTR   21:04:41 
insert  query update delete getmore command  vsize    res faults  netIn netOut  conn repl       time 
    68     53     37      0       0     314  1.02g    62m      0    85k   241k     7  RTR   21:04:56 
    65     53     41      0       0     319  1.02g    62m      0    85k   229k     3  RTR   21:05:11 
    71     55     40      0       0     337  1.02g    62m      0    91k   274k    14  RTR   21:05:26 
    63     47     35      0       0     297  1.07g    63m      0    79k   220k    63  RTR   21:05:41 
    64     52     37      0       0     298  1.02g    62m      0    81k   230k     7  RTR   21:05:56 
    67     53     39      0       0     322  1.02g    62m      0    87k   230k     4  RTR   21:06:11 
    68     53     38      0       0     321  1.02g    62m      0    86k   273k     3  RTR   21:06:26 
    70     56     41      0       0     336  1.02g    62m      0    90k   275k     3  RTR   21:06:41 
    64     51     38      0       0     310  1.02g    62m      0    82k   220k     4  RTR   21:06:56 
    66     51     38      0       0     315  1.02g    62m      0    84k   290k    21  RTR   21:07:11 
insert  query update delete getmore command  vsize    res faults  netIn netOut  conn repl       time 
    62     50     38      0       0     299  1.02g    62m      0    80k   240k     5  RTR   21:07:26 
    65     49     36      0       0     308  1.02g    62m      0    82k   235k    36  RTR   21:07:41 
    68     51     36      0       0     298  1.02g    62m      0    81k   255k     6  RTR   21:07:56 
    69     53     37      0       0     319  1.02g    62m      0    85k   235k     5  RTR   21:08:11 
    66     52     37      0       0     312  1.02g    62m      0    84k   236k     6  RTR   21:08:26 
    65     51     36      0       0     305  1.02g    62m      0    82k   214k     5  RTR   21:08:41 
    68     53     38      0       0     320  1.02g    62m      0    85k   265k     9  RTR   21:08:56 
    70     53     36      0       0     319  1.02g    62m      0    85k   226k    19  RTR   21:09:11 
    69     52     37      0       0     312  1.02g    62m      0    84k   270k     4  RTR   21:09:26 
    67     51     36      0       0     311  1.04g    63m      0    83k   256k    19  RTR   21:09:41 
insert  query update delete getmore command  vsize    res faults  netIn netOut  conn repl       time 
    70     54     40      0       0     325  1.02g    62m      0    88k   288k     4  RTR   21:09:56 
    69     52     36      0       0     317  1.03g    62m      0    85k   272k    14  RTR   21:10:11 
    67     53     39      0       0     321  1.03g    62m      0    86k   253k    13  RTR   21:10:26 
    70     55     39      0       0     330  1.03g    62m      0    88k   264k    12  RTR   21:10:41 
    70     54     39      0       0     332  1.03g    63m      0    89k   264k    30  RTR   21:10:56 
    69     52     36      0       0     319  1.07g    63m      0    85k   288k    73  RTR   21:11:11 
    61     43     32      0       0     291  1.19g    66m      0    75k   250k   208  RTR   21:11:26 
    62     42     30      0       0     285  1.32g    68m      0    74k   252k   321  RTR   21:11:41 
    66     52     38      0       0     315  1.33g    69m      0    84k   274k   341  RTR   21:11:56 
    68     42     30      0       0     302  1.51g    72m      0    78k   217k   500  RTR   21:12:11 
insert  query update delete getmore command  vsize    res faults  netIn netOut  conn repl       time 
    53     27     20      0       0     256  1.78g    77m      0    62k   175k   780  RTR   21:12:26 
    22     19     15      0       0     244  1.77g    78m      0    58k   158k   771  RTR   21:12:41 
    21     17     11      0       0     245  1.75g    77m      0    59k   139k   755  RTR   21:12:56 
     7      4      3      0       0     218  1.77g    78m      0    49k   103k   772  RTR   21:13:11 
     2      1      0      0       0     214  1.77g    77m      0    47k    85k   773  RTR   21:13:26 
     0      0      0      0       0     208  1.77g    77m      0    45k    79k   773  RTR   21:13:41 
    61     60     41      0       0     323  1.49g    73m      0    91k   338k   489  RTR   21:13:56 
    79     73     50      0       0     358  1.16g    65m      0   104k   328k   153  RTR   21:14:11 
    74     50     32      0       0     315  1.22g    66m      0    84k   241k   220  RTR   21:14:26 
    72     51     35      0       0     303  1.19g    66m      0    83k   290k   189  RTR   21:14:41 
insert  query update delete getmore command  vsize    res faults  netIn netOut  conn repl       time 
    74     52     35      0       0     310  1.19g    66m      0    84k   224k   180  RTR   21:14:56 
    80     58     39      0       0     337  1.14g    65m      0    92k   344k   127  RTR   21:15:11 
    81     48     30      0       0     314  1.22g    67m      0    83k   242k   215  RTR   21:15:26 
    84     58     37      0       0     332  1.15g    65m      0    91k   275k   152  RTR   21:15:41 
    82     58     39      0       0     328   1.1g    64m      0    90k   331k    83  RTR   21:15:56 
    78     53     36      0       0     317  1.08g    64m      0    86k   271k    89  RTR   21:16:11 
    82     47     32      0       0     314  1.19g    66m      0    83k   257k   200  RTR   21:16:26 
    80     52     37      0       0     318  1.24g    67m      0    85k   304k   234  RTR   21:16:41
```

Around 21:11:26, the amount of connections rapidly goes up without any significant increase in traffic.  You can see before that there is a long time when the connections are low and steady.

Can somebody point me in the right direction here?

### Answer Update

With help below, I was able to get a solution.  Basically, you put you `app.listen(port)` inside `db.open()`.  Then, outside of that, still in main.js, you pass a reference to db to your path handlers.  Then pass that all the way through to the actual db call were you get the collection and do your query.  Then don't call `db.close()` at all.

main.js:

```
mongodb = require('mongodb');
var serverOptions = {
  'auto_reconnect': true,
  'poolSize': 50
};
var serv = new mongodb.Server('localhost', 27017, serverOptions);
var db = new mongodb.Db('beacon', serv);

app.get('/log', function(req,res){          log.request(req,res, db)            });//writes events

db.open(function (error, db) {
      if (!module.parent) {
        app.listen(8888);
        console.log("Express server listening on port %d", app.address().port)
      }
});
```

log.js:

```
function request(req,res, db){
  //build val object
  database.writeRecord(db, val) 
}
```

database.js:

```
function writeRecord(db, value){
    collectionname='testwritespeed';
    db.collection(collectionname, function(err, collection) {
        collection.insert(value, function(err,doc){
            if(err) {  
                console.log('Insert ERROR!!!!! Is the database running? '+JSON.stringify(err));
            }
            console.log(doc)
            //don't do db.close() !!!!!
        }) // collection.insert
    }); //db.collection
}
```

Comment: It would be better to just open a single `Db` connection pool when your app starts and have all of these methods sharing it instead of opening and closing a pool on each call.

Comment: Can I have multiple requests access the same connection pool?  I found this example http://technosophos.com/content/nodejs-connection-pools-and-mongodb.  Where would my database functions go in that example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a new `Db` object and then call `open` on it, what you're actually doing is creating a connection pool of five connections (by default).  Then, when you call [`db.close`](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#close) without any parameters, the connections in the pool aren't actually closed, but left around in case they're needed again soon.

Because you're doing this in every call to your module, it's easy to see how you could run out of connections.

Instead, you should be creating a single `Db` pool of connections when you app starts that gets passed into your module (or the module creates itself) that all of the methods of your module can use.

The `Db` connection pool supports multiple outstanding operations up to the size of the connection pool.

main.js:

```
mongodb = require('mongodb');
var serverOptions = {
  'auto_reconnect': true,
  'poolSize': 50
};
var serv = new mongodb.Server('localhost', 27017, serverOptions);
var db = new mongodb.Db('beacon', serv);

app.get('/log', function(req,res){
  log.request(req,res, db);
});

db.open(function (error, db) { // Both the db var and the db parameter are the same object
  if (!module.parent) {
    app.listen(8888);
    console.log("Express server listening on port %d", app.address().port)
  }
});
```

database.js:

```
function writeRecord(db, value){
    collectionname='testwritespeed';
    db.collection(collectionname, function(err, collection) {
        collection.insert(value, function(err, doc){
            if (err) {
                console.log('Insert ERROR!!!!! Is the database running? '+JSON.stringify(err));
            }
            console.log(doc);
            // Do NOT close db here!
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: where would i define those connections? in main.js? request-handler.js? or database.js?  Can you link to an example please?  Also, it seems that db.open() doesn't return anything, and handles it work via a callback function.  How can I run db.open on init, and then have it's callback function run something at a request in the future?

Comment: @Landon Call `db.open` in `main.js` and in its callback pass `db` into your database handler module via a method call and then start listening for requests.

Comment: Do I put my `app.get('/path',function(res,req){})` **in** the `db.open()` callback function?  I put a simplified version of what I have in my question above.  It seems odd to put a request handler inside of a `db.open` callback function.  What I have above doesn't work, what do I need to change?

Comment: No, just the `app.listen(8888);` should go there so you don't listen for requests until `Db` is opened.

Comment: I don't understand, how would `request` get the `db` variable if that line isn't in the `open` callback function?  Would you mind just copying my main.js into your answer and moving things around to where they are supposed to be? I would really appreciate it.  I've been working on this for the better part of today ....

Comment: That did it!  I still had db.close() in there which obviously was closing things pretty quick :).  Thanks for your help.  I couldn't find any example out there that did mongo connection pooling *and* handled http requests.  So I don't need `db.close()` anywhere?

Comment: @Landon No, that would close the entire pool of connections.